# Remove space recursively in string

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to remove multiple white spaces from my table, that contains 40+ columns with string values in it and about 150K rows.

Using CURSOR, I came up with the following solution (as part of my stored procedure that populates my table), however this does not remove the white spaces in single run. If I run the update statements alone manually multiple times, spaces are removed completely. Any idea on how I can clean up my data in single run?

```
Declare @col nvarchar(128)
Declare StringCol CUSRSOR for
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
     AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
OPEN StringCol
FETCH NEXT FROM StringCol into @col;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
   BEGIN
     UPDATE  TableName
     SET     @col = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@col, '  ', ' '))) 
     WHERE   @col LIKE '%  %'

    FETCH NEXT FROM StringCol into @col
END

CLOSE StringCol
Deallocate StringCol

END
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert double spaces to single spaces, or remove all spaces altogether?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2016 you can use `STRING_Split` or similar UDF functions for other versions. The trick is convert the words into columns, take the non-space and bring them back to one value

```
Declare @col nvarchar(128)
Declare StringCol CUSRSOR for
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
     AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
OPEN StringCol
FETCH NEXT FROM StringCol into @col;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
   BEGIN
     UPDATE  TableName
     SET     @col = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 
               (
                 select Value + ' ' 
                   from STRING_SPLIT (@col, ' ') 
                 where value <>'' for xml path('')
               )
            )
     WHERE   @col LIKE '%  %'

    FETCH NEXT FROM StringCol into @col
END

CLOSE StringCol
Deallocate StringCol

END
```

If you use pre-SQL Server 2016, then this a UDF `STRING_SPLIT` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT]
(
    @String nvarchar(max),      -- String to be parsed
    @Delm nchar(1)=','
)
returns @Table TABLE (/*ID int identity(1,1), */ value nvarchar(max))
Begin
    INSERT @Table(value) 
    SELECT ltrim(t.val.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))  AS value  
    FROM(
            SELECT Convert(XML, '<M>' + REPLACE(@String, @Delm, '</M><M>') + '</M>') AS x 
        ) AS A CROSS APPLY x.nodes ('/M') AS t(val)
    Return
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
-- code #1
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[AllTrim] (@Texto varchar(8000))
returns table as
return
with xTrim as (
SELECT Rep= 1,
       Trimmed= Replace(Ltrim(Rtrim(@Texto)), space(2), space(1))

union all

SELECT Charindex(space(2), Trimmed),
       Replace(Trimmed, space(2), space(1))
  from xTrim
  where Rep > 0
)  
SELECT Trimmed
  from  xTrim 
  where Rep = 0;
go
```

---

Demo to use:

```
-- code #2
declare @TableName table (col1 varchar(200), col2 varchar(800));

INSERT into @TableName values
   (' aa       aaa    aaaa       a ', 'b   b  ');

SELECT T1.col1, T2.Trimmed as [col1 trimmed], 
       T1.col2, T3.Trimmed as [col2 trimmed]
  from @TableName as T1
       outer apply dbo.AllTrim(T1.col1) as T2
       outer apply dbo.AllTrim(T1.col2) as T3;
```

---

Demo to update:

```
-- code #3
declare @TableName table (ID int identity, 
                          col1 varchar(200), col2 varchar(800));

INSERT into @TableName (col1, col2) values
   (' aa       aaa    aaaa       a ', 'b   b  '),
   ('xxx       xx   xx   xxxxx', NULL);

with tbTrimmed as (
SELECT T1.ID, 
       T2.Trimmed as [col1 trimmed], 
       T3.Trimmed as [col2 trimmed]
  from @TableName as T1
       outer apply dbo.AllTrim(T1.col1) as T2
       outer apply dbo.AllTrim(T1.col2) as T3
)       
UPDATE TN
  set col1= [col1 trimmed],
      col2= [col2 trimmed]
  from @TableName as TN
       inner join tbTrimmed as Tr on TN.ID = Tr.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CLR functions you could do this using a regular expression:

```
Declare cnvarchar(max)
Declare @col nvarchar(128)
Declare StringCol CUSRSOR for
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
     AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
OPEN StringCol
FETCH NEXT FROM StringCol into @col;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
   BEGIN

    --{ this is the key bit
    set @sql ='
    UPDATE  TableName
    SET     ' + quotename(@col) + ' = dbo.RegexReplace(ltrim(rtrim(' + quotename(@col) + ')), ''\s\s+'', ' '
    WHERE   ' + quotename(@col) + ' LIKE ''%  %'' 
    or      ' + quotename(@col) + ' LIKE '' %'' 
    or      ' + quotename(@col) + ' LIKE ''% '' 

    '
    --} this is the key bit

    --print @sql --for debugging
    exec @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM StringCol into @col

END

CLOSE StringCol
Deallocate StringCol

END
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx for related CLR code.